Using sentry on android make app crash when ndk error happens
I'm using Sentry on an Android project using UVCCamera library, sometimes I get some errors like
 invalid pthread_t 0x71e13cbcb0 passed to pthread_getcpuclockid
 Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 2237 (Sampling Profil), pid 2180(package name)

Before using Sentry, when I got this error I ignored it and the app still worked, but after integrating Sentry, every time this error happened, the app crashed.
Looking through Sentry's doc and finding nothing can help me make the app not crash.
Any suggestion would be appreciated, thank you!

The error indicates an attempt to use an invalid thread ID (pthread_t) with the pthread_getcpuclockid function. This could happen when a thread being destroyed before the pthread_getcpuclockid call or using a thread ID from a different process. Seems like conflict between Sentry's threading model and the UVCCamera library. Check the library's documentation or contact the developers for known issues and workarounds.

This sounds like the following issue https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/2604, could you share some more details on the GitHub ticket?

Thank you @Markus Hi , it's a similar one, according to that discussion, I've tried enableTracing=false , then no crash. set activityFramesTracking, the crash still exists.
